# Unable to autoincrement primary Key with SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SQLAlchemy ORM in Django for Snowflake , and Now am not able to insert new row.

```
class Notification(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dq_notification_list'
    dq_notification_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    contact_name = Column(String(200))
    distribution_type = Column(String(200))
    distribution_address = Column(String(500))
    description = Column(String(1000))
    row_created_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    row_updated_date = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    def __init__(self,contact_name,distribution_type,distribution_address):
        self.contact_name = contact_name
        self.distribution_type = distribution_type
        self.distribution_address = distribution_address


def notification_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        type = request.POST['type']
        email = request.POST['email']
        user = Notification(contact_name = name, distribution_type = type, distribution_address = email)
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()
    else:
        form = NotificationForm()]
    return render(request, "notification_form.html")
```

> (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100072 (22000): NULL
> result in a non-nullable column [SQL: INSERT INTO dq_notification_list
> (dq_notification_id, contact_name, distribution_type,
> distribution_address, description, row_created_date, row_updated_date)
> VALUES (%(dq_notification_id)s, %(contact_name)s,
> %(distribution_type)s, %(distribution_address)s, %(description)s,
> %(row_created_date)s, %(row_updated_date)s)] [parameters:
> {'dq_notification_id': None, 'contact_name': 'Ansal',
> 'distribution_type': 'As', 'distribution_address':
> 'ansal.ka@gmail.com', 'description': None, 'row_created_date':
> datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 20, 13, 27, 52, 333777),
> 'row_updated_date': None}] (Background on this error at:
> http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

Comment: Skip/remove the primary key column in your insert, otherwise Python adds automatically None value which is equivalent of NULL: 'dq_notification_id': None, and you get the error then.

Comment: @Sergiu But the object is created with that column only , so how we can skip that column when session.add(user)

Comment: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/117